# scala-ide error only classes can have declared but undefined members

Tags: scala

I have code like this

```
object API {

    val apiBaseUrl = "https://api.com/2/"

    def getUserDetails(id: String, pass: String): Map[String, String] {
        val apiRequestUrl = apiBaseUrl + "?id=" + id + "&pass=" + pass
    }
}
```

This gives me error `only classes can have declared but undefined members` for line starting with `def` and error `only declarations allowed here` for line starting with `val apiRequestUrl`. But when i change the above code to(just put an equals sign after the method signature)

```
object API {

    val apiBaseUrl = "https://api.com/2/"

    def getUserDetails(id: String, pass: String): Map[String, String] = {
        val apiRequestUrl = apiBaseUrl + "?id=" + id + "&pass=" + pass
    }
}
```

there is no error. Is there a difference between the above 2 definitions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is there a difference between the above 2 definitions?

Yes. In Scala, you have to use an equals sign for method bodies that return a value. So your second code fragment is more correct.

The first code fragment is parsed like this, I believe:

```
object API {
    val apiBaseUrl = "https://api.com/2/"

    def getUserDetails(id: String, pass: String): Map[String, String]

    {
      val apiRequestUrl = apiBaseUrl + "?id=" + id + "&pass=" + pass
    }
}
```

This explains the error about the missing body for `getUserDetails` and the error about the block `{ ... }` where a declaration is expected.